# Change in eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $2\times 2$ real positive operators which are given. Is there any general formula for the eigenvalues of 
\begin{equation}
S_n=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & i \\ -i & 0 \end{bmatrix} (X^n +Y^n)
\end{equation}
for each $n$? We can assume that $X+Y>0$ i.e. it is strictly positive. Note that, the above matrix is no more Hermitian and eigenvalues are of the form $\pm \lambda_n$. I am interested in the absolute value, i.e. $\lambda_n>0$.

If we can not have any exact formula, is there any lower or upper bound of $\lambda_n$ in terms of $\lambda_1$, say?